# Don't pluck flowers

Tags: prepositions

> 1. "Don't pluck flowers in the garden."
> 2. "Don't pluck flowers from the garden."

Which preposition should I use in the above sentence?

Comment: Of possible tangential interest: *[What is wrong in “Please don't pluck the flowers”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43597)* at EL&U.

Answer (score 6):

Both sentences are valid, but they differ slightly in meaning.

> Don't pluck flowers in the garden. (Just look at them, please.)

Refers to the position of the person doing the picking.

> Don't pluck flowers from the garden. (Get them from the meadow.)

Refers to the origin of the flowers.

So depending on what you want to say, choose the appropriate phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> Don't pluck flowers (that are) **in** the garden.

when emphasizing the location of the flowers.

> Don't pluck flowers **from** the garden.

Since "plucking flowers" implies that they will be taken somewhere else, this form emphasizes that they will be *removed* from the garden.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of these areas where either preposition will work fine, because they both essentially amount to the same thing.

When you pluck a flower that's ***in*** the garden, you also pluck a flower ***from*** the garden. That's what happens when you pluck flowers – especially since flowers aren't usually reattached to their stems after plucking.

So, in this context (that is, when the verb is *pluck* and the object is *flowers*), the preposition *in* describes **where the flowers are before plucking**, and the preposition *from* describes **where the flowers are plucked from**. In both cases, the location is *the garden*, and both sentences sound quite natural.

These two prepositions aren't always so interchangeable, though. It hinges on the verb. For example, if the verb was *touch* and the object was *cookies*, I might say:

- Don't **touch** any of the cookies **in** that glass jar.

That's the same as saying:

- See those cookies in that glass jar? Don't touch any of them.

However, I probably wouldn't say:

- Don't **touch** any of the cookies **from** that glass jar.

unless they had already been removed from the jar for some reason. So, if I removed them from the jar and put them on the countertop, I might say:

- Don't **touch** any of those cookies **from** the glass jar. I'm wrapping them up and taking them to work tomorrow.

---

Here's one more example, with the verb **eat**:

- Don't **eat** any of the tomatoes **from** the garden.
  <sup>(**could mean the tomatoes are already picked, don't eat them, OR don't go out in the garden and start eating the tomatoes**)</sup>
- Don't **eat** any of the tomatoes **in** the garden.
  <sup>(**implies the tomatoes are still growing; don't pick them**)</sup>
  <sub>(**this sentence is ambiguous, though; it could also mean, "if you're going to eat the tomatoes, don't eat them in the garden -- bring them inside and wash them off first**)</sub>

Comment: How greatly detailed and clear this answer is. +1

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but they imply slightly different things.

> Don't pluck flowers from the garden.

That just means what it sounds like, but it could also imply ("don't pluck flowers from the garden," *pluck them from the field.*)

> Don't pluck flowers in the garden

This one is more going on the (in the garden).

> While you are *in the garden* don't pluck flowers.
>
> Don't pluck flowers that are *in the garden*